# Gradle equivalent of 'configurations.properties' file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an old maven project which I'm trying to migrate over to gradle for practice. It uses a `configurations.properties` file to configure different apks. For example, I would use it set a `boolean` for the target marketplace, and would do this from the command line like so:

`mvn install -DexampleFlag=true`

There are a few of these flags, and they are used at various points throughout the app. Is there a way to create this file using gradle?

Or, of course, if you have a better solution I'd be happy to hear that too.

---

**EDIT**

Okay, so I've got flavors, and I'm adding values to fields in the generated `BuildConfig` class like so:

```
android {
    flavor1 {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'EXAMPLE_FLAG', 'true'
    }
}
```

And that works for the main `app` subproject. However, I also have an `api` subproject which needs to be able to access the flags too - which it can't, as the `app` subproject is the one with the flavors. If it helps, the `api` subproject is a dependency of `app`.

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this wouldn't be managed using flags but by defining multiple *application flavors*. For more information on flavors, see the [Android Gradle plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

Comment: thanks for the help. So I'm now using flavors, but I now have another problem. See my edit.

Comment: What is an app-specific project dependency?

Comment: Sorry I meant (app) flavor specific.

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure I understand though how flavor-specific dependencies help me though. All flavors will access the flags, but the flag are set differently for each. Apologies if I'm being an idiot.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. According to the plugin docs, libs can have flavors too. Hence it should be possible to set the same flavors and flags for, say, `allprojects { ... }`. Perhaps you could also get rid of some flags by having flavor-specific code, rather than keeping all code together and exercising different parts of the code based on flags.